# Failed to config the https on the docker nginx container, always report time out

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

OS:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Release:    7.3.1611
Codename:   Core
```

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:05:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Server:

```
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:05:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Nginx image is the offical image (latest)

```
[root@iZ2zea8ff3mfutp3knnkyyZ ~]# docker images
 REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
 nginx               latest              3448f27c273f        2 weeks ago         109 MB
```

the command to run nginx：

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --network=stone --ip=172.18.0.10 --name nginx -v /var/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -v /var/nginx/conf/vhosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro -v /var/nginx/conf/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro -v /var/nginx/www:/usr/share/nginx:rw -v /var/nginx/log:/var/log/nginx:rw nginx
```

I store the certificate and private key in the /var/nginx/conf/certs, and mount it when running the nginx image, the https certificate is "extensive domain name" (eg: *.domain.com)

nignx config file

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

ssl_certificate     certs/1_domain.com_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key certs/2_domain.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

server_name         testfrontend.domain.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
 location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   172.18.0.11:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
 }

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.well-known {
    allow  all;
}
}
```

That's it, but when I visit the "testfrontend.domain.com" with Chrome, it is always report time out.

I use wget to test it, too. still report time out.

I have checked the acccess.log and error.log

the access.log is empty.

i turn the level of error.log to debug.
the following is the info it recorded

```
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.13.0
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 6.3.0 20170205 (Debian 6.3.0-6)
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 65536:65536
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2017/05/30 00:40:28 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, I made a stupid mistake, I am using ALiYun servers in China, except the firewall installed on the server, there is another firewall called security strategy, I should have open the 443 port on it, unfortunately i was not. ok that's the reason. Thanks, everyone. hope this can help someone.